# Countifs sheets formula to show thats >= date BUT not more than 30 days after that date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif

I have a quick Countifs question for sheets. I have a formula that is basically wanting to count everything thats is ">=" a cell with a date. so ie. countifs everything ">=" "1/1/2023, but no more than 30 days after "1/1/2023"? How would I do that?

Just try to reference everything after a date but no more than 30 days after that date

Answer (score 1):

Here's a generalized example for this case scenario:

```
=countifs(B:B,1,A:A,">="&D1,A:A,"<"&D1+30)
```

[image]